# Android studio Youtube API error 401 unauthorised

Tags: android, youtube-api, retrofit, youtube-data-api

i am currently working on Youtube-API in android studio. API is working fine in browser, but i am facing 2 problems in android studio. These are:
1) API is giving error while fetching data. Then i need to enable it again, only then it works again. Why ?
2) When my API is working fine even in browser, then i am getting **error 401 Unauthorised**.

Below is my Interface code:

```
public interface APInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLcVfz1-_0rj93LJZjzOHE6phn25MUK4lt&key=AIzaSy*****************&maxResults=50")
    void getData(@Part("") String name,Callback<Result> callback);
}
```

and MainActivity.java file is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Constant.url).build();
        APInterface apInterface = restAdapter.create(APInterface.class);
        apInterface.getData("",new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result result, Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failure!"+error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error:",""+error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using retrofit 1.9 and internet permission and gradle is ok. Please help.

Comment: Can you try specifying in your API key restriction that you're using it for "Android apps" and not "HTTP referrers". Or set it to "None" and see what happens. api-error-401-unauthorised

Comment: Sir, i tried both **None** and **Android apps** key restriction, but the problem is always same.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the similar problem I fixed it by removing the `Authorization header` from the `Retrofit`. Try this

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        client.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
        //client.addInterceptor(new AuthTokenInterceptor(sessionManager));
```

Comment: Hello Sir @JeffreyRajan, fetching data with OkHttpClient is not preferable. Above method is working fine for other APIs without using any converter and OkHttpClient. Also, please include more code about _Authorization header_. Thanks.